# c# calling endinvoke in callback, using generics

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, c#-2.0

Inisde the callback after `BeginInvoke`, `AsyncResult.AsyncDelegate` needs to be cast to proper type, only then `EndInvoke` is accessible.

But I am using generics, so do I need to define N callbacks for N generalized methods?

This is the class:

```
public class Async
    {
        public delegate object Func(); //void with no parameter
        public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg); //one parameter with result

        public static void Execute(IAsyncSubscriber subscriber, Func action)
        {
            action.BeginInvoke(Callback, subscriber);
        }

        public static void Execute<T, T1>(IAsyncSubscriber subscriber, T param, Func<T, T1> action)
        {
            action.BeginInvoke(param, Callback, subscriber);
        }

        private static void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)ar;
            IAsyncSubscriber subscriber = (IAsyncSubscriber)result.AsyncState;
            Func action = (Func) result.AsyncDelegate;
            object returnValue = action.EndInvoke(result); //To call endinvoke 
            subscriber.Callback(returnValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your assumption is correct. You will need to define `N` callbacks. On the bright side, you will only be doing this once, so no biggy, just a little repetitive work :)

Comment: ok, thanks!. Can you move your comment to answer, I will close this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways in which you can avoid defining N callbacks:

1. You can pass the corresponding EndInvoke method as state in the BeginInvoke call. e.g.

   ```
   private delegate T EndInvokeDelegate<T>(IAsyncResult ar);

   public static void Execute<T, T1>(IAsyncSubscriber subscriber, T param, Func<T, T1> action)
   {
       action.BeginInvoke(param, Callback<T1>, new object[]{subscriber, new new EndInvokeDelegate<T1>(action.EndInvoke)});
   }

   public static void Execute<T, T1, T2>(IAsyncSubscriber subscriber, T param1, T1 param2, Func<T, T1, T2> action)
   {
       action.BeginInvoke(param1, param2, Callback<T2>, new object[]{subscriber, new new EndInvokeDelegate<T2>(action.EndInvoke)});
   }

   private static void Callback<TR>(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
       object[] stateArr = (object[])ar.AsyncState;
       IAsyncSubscriber subscriber = (IAsyncSubscriber)stateArr[0];
       EndInvokeDelegate<TR> action = (EndInvokeDelegate<TR>)stateArray[1];
       TR returnValue = action(ar);
       subscriber.Callback(returnValue);
   }
   ```

   You can also make Callback non-generic by treating stateArray[1] as MultiCastDelegate and using DynamicInvoke on it but that would be slow.
2. For .Net 2.0 and 3.0, you can use reflection e.g.

   ```
   Type actionType= result.AsyncDelegate.GetType();
   var minfo = actionType.GetMethod("EndInvoke");
   object returnValue = minfo.Invoke(res.AsyncDelegate, new object[] { ar });
   ```
3. For .Net 4.0, you can use dynamic. e.g.

   ```
   dynamic action = result.AsyncDelegate; 
   object returnValue = action.EndInvoke(result);
   ```

Comment: Thanks. But its tagged c# 2.0. Calling a method with reflection is very under performance

Comment: Even dynamic is under performance. That is why point 1 was the best option but completely missed out that you have tagged it C# 2.0...

Comment: Included non-reflection solution for C# 2.0 as well

Comment: Won't work for Execute<T1, T2, T3> .. or any other Execute call other than <T, T1>. I researched enough before coming to SO. Its ok, I am content with N callbacks, np :). cheers.

Comment: I don't know what I am thinking...probably need some rest :) removing the edit as it is not correct

Comment: It occurs to me even the lambda is not correct here...removing that as well

Comment: @AseemGautam I understand you ok with using N callbacks but IMHO that would be repetitive code. For the benefit of others who might have a similar question, I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your assumption is correct. You will need to define `N` callbacks.

On the bright side, you will only be doing this once, so no biggy, just a little repetitive work :)